# odoo 8 xmlrpc can't write whole text

Tags: python, odoo-8, xml-rpc

I use python-docx to parse docx file, then use xmlrpc to write content to odoo res.partner. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from docx import Document

import xmlrpclib

username = 'admin' #the user
pwd = 'password'      #the password of the user
dbname = 'odoo8_win'    #the database

# OpenERP Common login Service proxy object
sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)

#replace localhost with the address of the server
# OpenERP Object manipulation service
sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')

mypath="D:\py_test_files"
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]

#open doc
for file in onlyfiles:
    cv_name = mypath + '\\' + file
    name = file
    document = Document(cv_name)
    l = [ paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') for paragraph in document.paragraphs];

    for i in l:
        cv = u"".join(i.decode('utf-8'))
        print cv  # correct without problems
    partner = {
       'name': name,
       'cv': cv,
    }
    #calling remote ORM create method to create a record
    partner_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'create', partner)
```

cv sample:

Education

National University Of Singapore            Bachelor Of Business Administration

There is no error when run this python, when I login in odoo to check the field, only can see last paragraph:

National University Of Singapore            Bachelor Of Business Administration

May I ask help how to sove this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Regarding your code

   partner = {
      'name': name,
      'cv': cv,
   }

   ## calling remote ORM create method to create a record

   partner_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'create', partner)

If 'cv' field is text and it had data, than sure it will works.

Make sure your assignemnt variable had right data first.

Try:

```
partner = {
   'name': 'SnippetBucket.com',
   'cv': 'ERP Business Solution...',
}

partner_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'create', partner)
```

As this workes,sure your cv data once filled, all works.

Comment: Thanks Tejas Tank, if use your sample, it works. So I found I need append my cv to a full text. the problem was solved.